# Why ValueError: could not convert string to float:?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm actually trying to create a plotly chart,
I have an Arduino nano sending DHT22's (temp/hum sensor) data to a Raspberry Pi via usb serial output, a python script is supposed to read data and stream it to plot.ly

The Arduino sketch:

```
#include "DHT.h"
#define MAX_ITER 10
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
DHT dht2(2, DHTTYPE);
int startbyte;
int i;
float auxTemp;
float auxHum;
float meanHum[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
float meanTemp[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht2.begin();
}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    startbyte = Serial.read();
    if (startbyte == 't')
    {
      meanHum[0] = 0.0;
      meanTemp[0] = 0.0;
      for (i=0;i<MAX_ITER;i++)
      {
        auxTemp = dht2.readTemperature();
        auxHum = dht2.readHumidity();
        meanTemp[0] += auxTemp/(float)MAX_ITER;
        meanHum[0] += auxHum/(float)MAX_ITER;
        delay(500);
      }
      Serial.print(meanTemp[0],4); Serial.print(",");
      Serial.print(meanHum[0],4); Serial.println("");
    }
  }
}
```

The sketch seems ok and returns temp and humidity when triggered by 't'

But when I try to run this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import serial
import time
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *


arduinoFile = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
logFile = 'log.csv'
sensorOutput = [0.0, 0.0]

py.sign_in('#####','#####')
stream_ids=['#####','#####']

my_data = Data([
    Scatter(x=[], y=[],
         name='Sensor 1 temperature',
         mode='lines',
         line= Line(color='rgba(250,30,30,0.9)',width=2.5),
         stream=dict(token=stream_ids[0],maxpoints=900)),
    Scatter(x=[], y=[],
         name='Sensor 1 humidity',
         mode='lines',
         line= Line(color='rgba(30,30,250,0.3)',width=2.5),
         stream=dict(token=stream_ids[1],maxpoints=900), yaxis='y2')
    ])

my_layout = Layout(
    title='GrowTemp',
    xaxis=XAxis(
         showline=True,
         linecolor='#bdbdbd',
         title='Time',
         showticklabels=True),
    yaxis=YAxis(
         showline=True,
         linecolor='#bdbdbd',
         title='Temperature [*C]',
         showticklabels=True,
         titlefont=Font(size=18,color='#ee3333')),
    yaxis2=YAxis(
         showline=True,
         linecolor='#bdbdbd',
         title='Relative humidity [%]',
         titlefont=Font(size=18,color='#3366dd'),
         side='right',
         overlaying='y'),
    legend=Legend(x=0,y=1), showlegend=True
    )

my_fig = Figure(data=my_data, layout=my_layout)
py.plot(my_fig, filename='GrowTemp')
time.sleep(3)

s1temp = py.Stream(stream_ids[0])
s1hum = py.Stream(stream_ids[1])

ser = serial.Serial(arduinoFile, baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=10)
time.sleep(1)
ser.flushInput()

def gettemp():
    ser.write('t')
    ser.flush()
    return ser.readline().strip('\r').strip('\n')

timeStart = time.time()
while True:
    timeDelay = time.time()-timeStart
    timeStamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    sensorOutputString = gettemp()
    sensorOutputRaw = sensorOutputString.split(',')
    sensorOutput[0] = float(sensorOutputRaw[0]) 
    sensorOutput[1] = float(sensorOutputRaw[1]) 
    resultString = str(timeDelay)+','+timeStamp+','+str(sensorOutput[0])+','+str(sensorOutput[1])
    print(resultString)

    my_file = open(logFile,'a')
    my_file.write(resultString+'\n')
    my_file.close()
    s1temp.open()
    s1hum.open()
    s1temp.write(dict(x=timeStamp,y=sensorOutput[0]))
    s1hum.write(dict(x=timeStamp,y=sensorOutput[1]))
    s1temp.close()
    s1hum.close()
    time.sleep(50)

ser.close()
```

I have an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plotlyscript.py", line 74, in <module>
    sensorOutput[0] = float(sensorOutputRaw[0])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I found several posts about this ValueError, but I still can't figure out what's wrong here (I'm a total noob ;)) Is it because the string returns null value or a conflict with previous [0] [1] arguments?

Comment: try outputting the value of `sensorOutputRaw` and seeing what you get. my bets are that  there is a character that you are expecting in it (ie, a space or something). strings can only be explitly changed to floats if it only has numbers and one period.

Comment: This is arduino serial output data

Comment: How can I simply output the value of  `sensorOutputRaw`?

Comment: just put a `print(sensorOutputRaw)` right before the `sensorOutput[0]` crash. it should still print before it crashes.

Comment: Ok, seems that I have a null value, `print(sensorOutputRaw)` gave me `['']`

Comment: probably something wrong with your serial connection then

Comment: I still don't get it, I tried a few changes but no success, but when I run `>>> import time
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=10)
>>> time.sleep(1)
>>> ser.flushInput()
>>> ser.write('t')
1
>>> ser.readline().strip('\n').strip('\r')` in python, it seems to return correct values:
`'20.1400,65.3400'`

Comment: try passing in `ser` as a parameter in gettemp. Im not sure but I know there are some weird intricacies with python global variables

Comment: by "passing in `ser` as a parameter in gettemp, you mean: `def gettemp():
    ser = serial.Serial(arduinoFile, baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=6)
    time.sleep(1)
    ser.flushInput()
    ser.write('t')
    return ser.readline().strip('\r').strip('\n')` ? If so, doesn't change anything... thanks anyway!!

Comment: no, more so something like `def gettemp(serial)` and when you call it like `gettemp(ser)` so you're not dealing with a global variable inside of the function, ie handle with `serial` rather than `ser`

Comment: I wrote: `def gettemp(serial)` and `sensorOutputString = gettemp(ser)` but still the same ValueError.

Comment: did you just changed the calls to `ser` in the function to `serial`? btw, this is just an experiment, so if nothing happens, its probably something else

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, I'm a total beginner in coding, I guess I did it like you told me but still the same result. Thx for your time @RNar

Comment: another thing you can try is to do a `while sensorOutputString == ''` then make it call gettemp in the loop. It might have something to do with not connecting to your serial port. I'm sorry i can't help more, i don't have a lot of experience with pyserial

Comment: Thanks, I finally managed to make it run bypassing the `gettemp` def, and including gettemp`ser.write('t')` just above the `float` lines. The script looks  a bit messier now but anyway...  it'll do the trick!

Comment: you might want to add this as an answer then set it as the correct answer. that's really strange behavior tho, i have a feeling it has to do with how you were passing `ser` and `serial` in and how python interprets global variables. good to hear its working though!